# Assigning a TextComponent object differently based on try catch

Tags: java, try-catch, variable-assignment, bukkit

I'm trying to take a String `kd` and either assign it to a `TextComponent` object, or if the string can be parsed into a Double value then assign it to a `TextComponent` using a `DecimalFormat` object.

I check for known strings and do it this way, like this:

```
final TextComponent kd;
if (PlayerMeta.getStats(target).kd.contains("!") || PlayerMeta.getStats(target).kd.contains("null")) {
    kd = new TextComponent("K/D: " + PlayerMeta.getStats(target).kd);
} else {
    kd = new TextComponent("K/D: " + new DecimalFormat("#.###").format(Double.parseDouble(PlayerMeta.getStats(target).kd)));
}
```

but i want to catch all non-double-parsable strings to be handled at once.

I can't do this because kd would get assigned twice when string cannot be parsed:

```
final TextComponent kd;
try {
    kd = new TextComponent("K/D: " + new DecimalFormat("#.###").format(Double.parseDouble(PlayerMeta.getStats(target).kd)));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    kd = new TextComponent("K/D: " + PlayerMeta.getStats(target).kd);
}
```

What is the most compact way to achieve my goal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know I guess writing it out here helped me see what the issue seems to have been.

When using an if block, the TextComponent needs to be final and null beforehand, but **not** with try / catch.

I just removed the `final` and now it compiles, though I haven't tested the plugin again yet.